# 4 Camera Instant Replay

Tags: live

I am doing a live stream and would like the following video flow.  I am able to handle all parts of this except for the Instant Replay.  How could I accomplish the instant replay?

I have 4 PoE Pan Tilt Camera that output RTSP streams.  Currently I use OBS and take in the RTSP streams, do overlays and other stuff, and the stream to the internet.

I am in need of a solution that would allow me to be able to do instant replays of any camera with the overlay on it, and live stream this.